# Can you schedule an eth transfer in the future?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, sendrawtransaction, off-chain

Is it possible for person A to schedule an eth transfer to person B 1 week in the future, possibly by offchain signing the transaction?

I've seen the concept of offchain signing and am wondering if person A could offchain sign the eth transfer, that way they pay no gas and transfer no eth the day of signing. But 1 week later person B can execute the transaction, pay the gas fee, and receive the eth from person A all at once.

Is this scenario possible with the native currency of eth, ideally w/ a popular wallet? It seems it's possible w/ erc-20 tokens if they've implemented their contracts to allow it but I would like to do this with eth.

Answer (score 1):

Signing a transaction, and broadcasting it to the network are 2 distinct steps, so it is possible for the broadcast to be done 1 week later.

But if A sends the signed transaction to B, A cannot prevent B from broadcasting it immediately.

There might not be a popular wallet because the user experience could involve a format or file for the signed transaction, person A would need to send this to person B, who then needs to import it into their wallet, and then broadcast it to the network.

Also, until EIPs related to Account Abstraction are implemented, the signer always pays the gas fee.